# Print array elements in reverse order

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

The first line contains an integer N, (the size of our array).
The second line contains N space-separated integers describing array's(A's) elements.

I have tried the following, however I looked at the solution page. However I do not understand how this code works. Can someone please explain it to me. I am pretty new in this coding world.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = [int(arr_one) for arr_one in input().strip().split(' ')]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(str(arr[-i-1]), end = " ")
```

input 1234
output 4 3 2 1

Comment: the input is not space seperated. Is it the right input?

Answer (score 2):

In Python3:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    print(" ".join(str(x) for x in arr[::-1]))
```

Input:

```
1 4 3 2
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list of integer values, by removing spaces and splitting the values at `' '`. After obtaining the list of integers, you are iterating over the list and converting the ith element from the back (a negative value of index denotes element with ith index from right and it is 1 based) of arr back to string and printing the number.

Example:

```
 arr = [1,2,3,4]
 print(arr[1])  #prints 2 on the console, i.e 2nd element from the left.
 print(arr[-1]) #prints 4 on the console, i.e 1st element from the right.
```

Comment: If this helps, you can upvote it, so that it can be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this code snippet

```
n = int(input())
arr = [int(arr_one) for arr_one in input().strip().split(' ')]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(str(arr[-i-1]), end = " ")
```

The method `input()` will take the user input from key board. `int(input())` will convert the input into `int`, if the input is in string format. like "4" instead of 4. The input value stored into variable `n`.

*The Array input will be like this "1 2 3 4". So, we need to separate the string with space delimiter.*

The `strip()` method returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing characters removed.

The `split()` method returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.Here the separator is space. So, `split(' ')`

`input().strip().split(' ')` will take "1 2 3 4" as input and the output is *`"1"  "2"  "3"  "4"`.*

Now we need to take each element after separated. And then covert into int and store into array.

```
arr = [int(arr_one) for arr_one in input().strip().split(' ')]
```

`arr_one` is a variable, this variable stores each element after split. For each element, we converted it into `int` and then storing into a array `arr`.

In python, array index start from 0. If we want to access from last index in the array, the index will start from -1, -2, -3, and so on.

`for i in range(len(arr)):` The for loop will iterate from index 0 to length of the array. in this example, size is 4.
printing array elements from index -1. and the `end` argument is used to end the `print` statement with given character, here the end character is `" "`. So the output will be *`4 3 2 1`*.

Comment: Thank you so much for time and the effort in explaining !

Answer (score -1):

The above code can be rewritten as below with more readability.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    inp = input("Enter the numbers seperated by spaces:::")
    inp = inp.strip() # To remove the leading and trailing spaces
    array = []
    for item in inp.split(' '):     # Splitting the input with space and iterating over each element
        array.append(int(item))     # converting the element into integer and appending it to the list

    print(array[::-1])  # here -1 says to display the items in the reverse order. Look into list comprehension for more details
```

For more details on list slicing, look in the python documentation.

Comment: The OP is asking for an explanation of existing code (that's likely intentionally avoiding slicing), not a "better way to do it". This answer kind of misses the point.

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input()) # input as int from stream
arr = [int(arr_one) for arr_one in input().strip().split(' ')]
"""
1. asking for input from user
2. strip() function removes  leading and trailing characters.
3. split(' ') function split your input on space into list of characters
4. arr_one variable contains yours splited character and your iterating over it using for loop
5. int(arr_one) converts it into integer and  [] is nothing just storing everything into another list.
6. In last you are assigning new list to arr variable
"""
for i in reversed(arr): # loop over list in reverse order with built in fucntion
    print(i, end = " ") # printing whatever comes in i
```

It should work like this:

```
3 # your n 
1 2 3 # your input
3 2 1 # output
```

Comment: The OP is asking for an explanation of the existing code, not improved code.